# nearest k neighbours that satisfy conditions (python)

Tags: python, constraints, nearest-neighbor, kdtree

I have a slight variant on the *"find k nearest neighbours"* algorithm which involves rejecting those that don't satisfy a certain condition and I can't think of how to do it efficiently.

What I'm after is to find the k nearest neighbours that are in the current line of sight. Unfortunately `scipy.spatial.cKDTree` doesn't provide an option for searching with a filter to conditionally reject points.

The best algorithm I can come up with is to query for n nearest neighbours and if there aren't k that are in the line of sight then query it again for 2n nearest neighbours and repeat. Unfortunately this would mean recomputing the n nearest neighbours repeatedly in the worst cases. The performance hit gets worse the more times I have to repeat this query. On the other hand setting n too high is potentially wasteful if most of the points returned aren't needed.

The line of sight changes frequently so I can't recompute the `cKDTree` each time either. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for the neighbours in a line of sight, couldn't use an method like

> cKDTree.query_ball_point(self, x, r, p, eps)

which allows you to query the KDTree for neighbours that are inside a radius of size *r* around the *x* array points.
Unless I misunderstood your question, it seems that the line of sight is known and is equivalent to this *r* value.

Comment: The line of sight in this problem is described by a polygon that satisfies the following condition: A line from any arbitary point within it to the point queried has no intersection with a predefined set of edges. [example](http://www.blog.samclifton.com/?p=31) So alas the radius isn't fixed.